# How to access parameter from graphql query

Tags: vue.js, graphql, datocms

Using DatoCMS, with VueJS and gridsome. The page query looks like

```
<page-query>
{
  DatoCms {
    _site {
      globalSeo {
        facebookPageUrl
        siteName
        titleSuffix
        twitterAccount
        fallbackSeo {
          description
          title
          twitterCard
          image {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</page-query>
```

Below does not work to get the values from the query

```
export default {
  metaInfo: {
    title: this.$page.DatoCms._site[0].globalSeo.fallbackSeo.title,
```

Answer (score 1):

the query needed to be adjusted and metainfo method updated